# how to authenticate user name and password in javamail

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, jakarta-mail, webmail

I wanted to crating email client app in android, [oauth](http://oauth.net/) will authenticate for Google and yahoo, but want to use [oauth](http://oauth.net/) for other mail client like web mail how can I authenticate?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want to do.  Do you want to use OAuth with a different mail server?  Do you want to write your own mail server that uses OAuth?  Do you want to write a web mail (html+javascript) client that runs in the web browser in Android?

Comment: i want to use OAuth with different mail server..

Comment: Then you need to ask the owner of that mail server how to generate the OAuth tokens you'll need when authenticating to that mail server.  Sadly, the token generation process isn't completely standardized.